# radio buttons and a textview inside alert dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to make a dialog alert box with 3 radio buttons and a textview.But when i try to run it with 3 radio buttons,it runs fine,as i add the textview,the application shows the exception.

```
private void Dialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //  tv1=new TextView(this);
    //  rb1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");
        rb1=new RadioButton(this);
        rb1.setText("10 minutes");
        rb2=new RadioButton(this);
        rb2.setText("20 minutes");
        rb3=new RadioButton(this);
        rb3.setText("30 minutes");
        rb1.setOnClickListener(RadioOptionOnClickListener);
        rb2.setOnClickListener(RadioOptionOnClickListener);
        rb3.setOnClickListener(RadioOptionOnClickListener);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(1); 
private void Dialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //  tv1=new TextView(this);
    //  rb1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");
        rb1=new RadioButton(this);
        rb1.setText("10 minutes");
        rb2=new RadioButton(this);
        rb2.setText("20 minutes");
        rb3=new RadioButton(this);
        rb3.setText("30 minutes");
        rb1.setOnClickListener(RadioOptionOnClickListener);
        rb2.setOnClickListener(RadioOptionOnClickListener);
        rb3.setOnClickListener(RadioOptionOnClickListener);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(1);  
    //  linearLayout.addView(tv1);
        linearLayout.addView(rb1);
        linearLayout.addView(rb2);
        linearLayout.addView(rb3);
        alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

this is the exception sir

```
07-15 16:23:30.081: W/dalvikvm(1129): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at test.test.AlertdialogActivity.Dialog(AlertdialogActivity.java:32)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at test.test.AlertdialogActivity.access$0(AlertdialogActivity.java:29)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at test.test.AlertdialogActivity$1.onClick(AlertdialogActivity.java:59)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-15 16:23:30.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the exception?

Comment: i have given the exception sir

Comment: `tv1=new TextView(this);
    //  rb1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");` her you are init the `tv1` but setting the value of `rd1`. :)

Comment: thanks sir for telling me the problem thanks a lot

Comment: @user1522540 I have posted it as answer..if it solve your problem then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo I think, you wrote:

```
  tv1=new TextView(this);
  rb1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");
```

while it should be

```
 tv1=new TextView(this);
 tv1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");
```

what you did gave a Null exception because rb1 was to be created in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
//tv1=new TextView(this); 
//rb1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");
```

here you are initialize the `tv1` but setting the value of `rb1`.

try

```
tv1=new TextView(this); 
tv1.setText("these are the time limit options for you");
```